# Python 2.7.13 configured with `--enable-optimizations` puts many trash logs

Tags: python-2.7

when I open python console and close it by `Ctrl` + `D`,it comes with many logs.
why? how can I get rid of this.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/python
```

> Python 2.7.13 (default, May 23 2017, 19:19:44)
>   [GCC 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-15)] on linux2
>   Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>   >>>  // close with `Ctrl` + `D`
>   profiling:/root/Python-2.7.13:Cannot create directory
>   profiling:/root/Python-2.7.13/Objects/bytes_methods.gcda:Skip
>   profiling:/root/Python-2.7.13:Cannot create directory
>   profiling:/root/Python-2.7.13/Python/structmember.gcda:Skip
>   profiling:/root/Python-2.7.13:Cannot create directory
>   profiling:/root/Python-2.7.13/Python/getcopyright.gcda:Skip
>   ...

Comment: How did you build it? It looks like you have a config problem.

Comment: @matt  `./configure --enable-optimizations`

Comment: Do you have to include the --prefix option or is /usr/local the default? It could be part of one of the optimizations.

Comment: using the defalut `/usr/local`

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me using Debian Stretch whilst installing Python 3.6.1.  I initially installed it with, "sudo make altinstall" which caused those errors.  However, if you install it as root rather than using sudo, the errors go away.

I answered this question a bit late but I hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I did `./configure --enable-optimizations`. Removing the `--enable-optimizations` flag before compilation and installation makes these messages go away.